# how do i eliminate it from selecting other status also When clicked on Mark All Checkbox

Tags: jquery

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cdkLkcdk/8/

In case I select a Status from the filter  (Say Pending) and check  MarkAll Checkbox , how do i eliminate it from selecting other status also

I tried to avoid this by using this condition

// For Selecting All Checkboxes

```
$(document).on('click', '#selectall', function (event) {
          var statuschecked = $('#filterstatus').val();
    if (this.checked) { // check select status
        $('.checkbox1').each(function () { //loop through each checkbox
            if($('.label').text()===statuschecked)
            {
            this.checked = true; //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"               
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('.checkbox1').each(function () { //loop through each checkbox
            this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"                       
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you delegate event handling to `document`? It is not needed because there is only a single element that matches `#selectall` and it's not created dynamically. And it has much worse performance. Better use `$('#selectall').on('change', handler)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach an event with your selectbox and look for its value to change.

```
$("#filterstatus").on("change",function(){
   if($('#selectall').is(':checked'))
   {   $('#selectall').attr('checked', false);
       $('.checkbox1').attr('checked', false);
   }

});        
});
```

Also, dont delegate any event to document root unless necessary.
Doing so will bubble your event straight from the triggered element to the document root.